# Unable to Insert data in an .mdf using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2013, mdf

I am trying to insert Data in an .mdf file using Entity Framework but there is no data saved in the database. (I am using VS 2013)

Code Against the Button is

```
private void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Product record = new Product();
        record.ProductName = txtProductName.Text;
        AzadIndustryEntities1 Db = new AzadIndustryEntities1();
        Db.Products.Add(record);
        Db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted");
    }
```

SQL against Products Table is

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Products] (
[ProductID]          INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[ProductName]        VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[ProductQuantity]    INT          NULL,
[PricePerUnit]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[ProductDescription] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
[UserID]             INT          NULL,
[CustomerID]         INT          NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Products] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProductID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_ToTable_Customer] FOREIGN KEY ([CustomerID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Customer] ([CustomerID]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Products_ToTable_Products] FOREIGN KEY ([UserID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserID])
```

);

Comment: What's the error you are seeing? Are you making sure all required non-null fields are set when you are adding? Hard to tell from just what you have there.

Comment: Can you step though your code using the debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: There is no error program is executingg without any Error or Exception.
There Is only one non-null field that is Product ID and it is auto generated.

Comment: What is Product? Your database entity? Because "Db.Products.Add(record);" Product does not match Products. Hard to tell with out more insight into your model.

Comment: Product is a model Class and Products is an entity to DB model

Comment: Not really understanding the set-up, i would assume their is no relation to your model object and entity object. I will add an answer to hopefully solve the issue.

Comment: How long does your Db (context) live ? Could you try to dispose it after SaveChanges?

Comment: @Tez Wingfield.
Simply I would say that **Products** is the table name in my database and **Product** is the model class that is generated by Visual Studio when I used  ADO.net Entity Data Model and added my **.mdf** file.

Comment: The below answer should work if using EF. If their is any pluralization, Switch Products to Product.

Comment: Please show the connection string.

Comment: Make sure your .mdf file isn't getting overwritten when you build.

Comment: @DStanley how can I prevent .mdf from overwriting ?

Comment: @Sameel check out [this article on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is solved. Going to explain it so that it could help others also.

As the default property of **.mdf** file **Copy to Output Directory** is **Copy always** so when we debug our program a copy of the .mdf file is copied in the **debug folder** which is in the **bin folder**  (Select **Show All Files** in **Solution Explorer** to view the bin folder) so, whatever changes we make in database through **code** it is saved in the **copied .mdf** that is in the debug folder. When we **debug** our program **again** the same steps are performed again and the previous database is **overwritten**. To prevent such happening the property of .mdf file mentioned above should be set to **Copy if newer** so, if there is any change in the model only then the .mdf will be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of instantiating the model object and adding to your entity object. Try direct access to your entity object:

```
private void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AzadIndustryEntities1 Db = new AzadIndustryEntities1();
        Products product = new Products();
        Products.ProductName = txtProductName.Text;
        Db.Products.Add(product);
        Db.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted");
    }
```

//EDITS - Hopefully a different approach will work.

```
private void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   AzadIndustryEntities1 Db = new AzadIndustryEntities1();
   Product p = new Product() { p.ProductName = txtProductName.Text };
   db.AddToProducts(p);
   db.SaveChanges();
 }
```

Comment: I cant use it because there is no such class **Products** exist in the .sln .

Comment: Apologies...Do you have the model viewer/Object viewer that EF creates for you?

Comment: sorry for late replying. Yes I do have the model viewer. Should I add its snap ?

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked for me before.

```
private void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   AzadIndustryEntities1 Db = new AzadIndustryEntities1();
   Product p = db.Products.Create()
   p.ProductName = txtProductName.Text;
   db.Products.Add(p);
   db.SaveChanges();
 }
```